# How to flip Angular Material Select panel side to make sure it stays inside the screen

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, mat-select

I have a `mat-select` inside my site's main navbar. It contains a list of currencies and is positioned at the right of the navbar. Since I strictly want to display the currency abbreviation (ex: USD) in my navbar, but want to display a flag icon, currency name, and abbreviation inside the panel, I decided to resize the panel to be larger than the select. This leads to a problem where the panel overflows the screen and is not displayed entirely. I was wondering if there was a simple way to make sure the panel stays inside the browser, in other words, make sure the panel position does not go past the end position of the select.

**Current Behavior:**

[image: Current Behavior]

**Desired Behavior:**

[image: Desired Behavior]

**HTML:**

```
<header>
    <mat-toolbar class="navbar">
      <button mat-icon-button aria-label="Menu Icon">
      <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <span>My Website</span>
      <div class="navbar-currency">
        <mat-form-field class="currency-select">
          <mat-select name="currency" panelClass="currency-panel" [(value)]="selectedCurrency">
            <mat-select-trigger>{{selectedCurrency}}</mat-select-trigger>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let currency of currencyArr" [value]="currency.key">
              <span class="fi fi-{{currency.icon}}"></span> {{currency.key }} - {{ currency.name}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
    </mat-toolbar>
</header>
```

**CSS:**

```
.navbar {
  background: #ffffff;
  display: flex;
  padding-left: 2rem;
  padding-right: 2rem;
}

.navbar-currency{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 1.3rem;
}

.currency-select{
  font-size: 0.85rem;
  width: 80px;
}

.currency-panel.mat-mdc-select-panel {
  font-size: 0.85rem;
  min-width: calc(100% + 120px)
}

.currency-panel.mat-mdc-select-panel .fi{
  margin-right: 0.1rem;
}

.currency-panel.mat-mdc-select-panel .mat-mdc-option{
  min-height: 36px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simple Solution**

If your Currency Mat-Select is always on the right side of the screen then you could solve this with some css. Set the container position to absolute and the right to zero:

```
.currency-panel.mat-mdc-select-panel {
  font-size: 0.85rem;
  min-width: calc(100% + 120px);
  position: absolute !important;
  right: 0;
}
```

**Mat-Menu Solution**

Use [Mat-Menu](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/examples) instead, which has a built in handling for the menu positioning. Mat-Select consider the width of your select element as the width of the dropdown select options and that does not require handling the left/right overflow.

You will just need to rewrite your css and you are good to go.

Component Template:

```
 <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" class="currency-select">
        <span>{{ selectedCurrency }}</span>
        <mat-icon
          fontIcon="arrow_drop_down"
          style="vertical-align: bottom"
        ></mat-icon>
      </button>

      <mat-menu #menu="matMenu" panelClass="currency-panel">
        <button
          *ngFor="let currency of currencyArr"
          mat-menu-item
          (click)="selectedCurrency = currency.key"
        >
          <span class="fi fi-{{ currency.icon }}"></span>{{ currency.key }} -
          {{ currency.name }}
        </button>
      </mat-menu>
```

Component CSS:

```
.navbar-currency {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.currency-select {
  font-size: 0.85rem;
}

.mat-mdc-menu-panel .fi {
  margin-right: 0.2rem;
}

.currency-panel .mat-mdc-menu-item {
  min-height: 36px;
}
```

[Checkout my stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5vfuhh?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

If your Mat-Select will be used on both corners, then you should write your own position handler for the Mat-Select.